# Apache Tomcat failed to start

Tags: macos, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I am using mac 15 inch retina eye display laptop currently running Sierra os . I am facing an issue from past few days apache tomcat does not start in netbeans. it gives an error port 8084 already in use. and when i try to change port to 8080 then it says starting of tomcat failed while 8082 port it says port already in use. Sometimes apache tomcat starts and then again it does the same port in use and unable to start. Please give me some solution to it.

Comment: I have a similar problem and it seems that Netbeans is unable to detect that Tomcat is already running since I upgraded to Mac OS X Sierra.

Comment: Yes thats y m not able to use it.. Please do u have any solution to it Raphael..

Answer (score 0):

That means that there is another instance of Tomcat running at the same time. If you are unable to stop already running Tomcat instance from Netbeans you can do it from command line.

1. Find Tomcat process id by executing `ps aux | grep tomcat`.
2. Stop Tomcat: `kill <pid>` or if for some reason it does not work to stop `kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 0):

That means process is already running.

Reasons
1. You might have checked start tomcat on start up.
2. And again you are trying to start in Netbeans

Solutions:
1. Reinstall and carefully check options.
2. Find and kill the process and start from netbeans

This might work. Try it

Answer (score 0):

1. Give all permissions to the catalina.sh script : chmod +x catalina.sh

Go to Preferences, and check the configuration

[image]

and, change the configuration to ...

[image]

In my case works, i hope it has been helpfull